# Finding the term in binomial theorem.

Tags: binomial-theorem

Please, how do I solve for the term in $x^2$ and the term independent of $x$ in the expansion of $(x^2 -  2/x^2)^4$?

Comment: (a) If you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typing math expressions, you won't have to explain what is where. (b) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am having issues in the part where you get the equation to help you solve for the two of them. I just need an illustration of how to get the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\left(x^2-\frac2{x^2}\right)^4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* The general term (indexed by $k$) in the expansion of this expression is given by $$\binom{4}{k}(x^2)^{4-k}\left(\frac{-2}{x^2}\right)^k=\binom{4}{k}x^{8-2k}(-2)^kx^{-2k}=(-2)^k\binom{4}{k}x^{8-2k-2k}=(-2)^k\binom{4}{k}x^{8-4k}.$$

Set the exponent of $x$ equal to $2$ to find out the corresponding value of $k$ needed, and equal to $0$ to find the term independent of $x.$

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Please, noobish question, but how is( x^2)^k equal to x^-2k? Sorry for bothering you, I am still learning.

Comment: @KingRoyal We have that $$\frac{1}{y}=y^{-1}$$ for any nonzero $y.$

Comment: Ok sir. So if it is (x^3)^k, it would be x^-3k. Am I correct? Thanks

Comment: Or, if I have (3/x^3)^r, it would be equal to x^-3r?

Comment: Or, if I have (3/x^3)^r, it would be equal to x^-3r?

Comment: If you had $(3/x^3)^r,$ that would be equal to $3x^{-3r}.$